# Absent window in CS 1.6

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike

I recently installed CS 1.6 from third party applications,

It worked fine for the first time but then I later added some skins then it didn't work then after uninstalling and re-installing the game, In the server section everything is absent except the maps which is being shown . I am running cs 1.6 in windows 7. Can any one help? [image]

Comment: what do you expect to see there? If I remember correctly there's nothing except for map selection in this tab, all settings are in *Game* tab

Comment: What does "from third party applications" mean?

Comment: @CamelCase Meaning he got it from a separate source than which he would normally.

Comment: To clarify, why couldn't you just download it through Steam like you regularly would?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the reason to that is in the application data.

Programms arent only saved in one location but are spread over multiple, uninstalling doesnt necessarily remove everything (settings and the like are mostly kept so they apply when you reinstall), so check your harddrive for anything that belongs to cs and delete it manually.

Comment: I tried your advice , but with no result .

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said, either the "third party application" or the skins were corrupted.

This resulted in the entire file being corrupted. It may even extend to the operating system/console. You may have to completely uninstall *everything* related to those files. This might fix the problem, but I can't guarantee anything without being able to identify the problem.

Answer (score -1):

To play online, make sure you're clicking the **Find Servers** button. If it's just maps showing up in the little window, look at the top at the tabs readjust them to your liking. If it's empty and nothing is showing up, you may need to go and download the MasterServers.vdf file for CS 1.6.